# In set theory, what does it mean for a variable to have a bar symbol above it?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Please see the image below.

[image]

What does the bar symbol mean in this context?

Comment: I think it means the complement of the set (here the complement of set B)

Comment: It means something, but it is used in .any different ways in different contexts. Try to find your textbook's first use of the notation. They should define it for you there.

Comment: Probably complement. However, I've seen people call something set theory when it's really elementary general topology. You would certainly see this exact symbology in that context, unambiguously meaning the *closure* of $B$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The complement of the set $B$, also commonly denoted as $B'$ or $B^c$. It is the set:

$$\bar{B} = B^c = B' = \{x \mid x \not \in B\}$$

Comment: Ahh. I had never seen this particular notation before. Thank you.